# Waypoint generator - Calculating round trip based on rules

Tags: c#, math, coordinates

I'm trying to work on a piece of code to return a list of waypoints which represent a flight path for a AI raid to fly. Unfortunately maths and trig were never my strong point so I've been googling and not getting very far very fast.

I have the following code

```
    public static Point2d CalculateCoordinate(double Angle, double Distance)
    {
        Point2d coord = new Point2d(Distance * Math.Cos(Angle), Distance * Math.Sin(Angle));
        return coord;
    }
    public static double GetAngle(Point2d coord1, Point2d coord2, Point2d coord3, Point2d coord4)
    {
        double result = 0.0;

        result = (Math.Atan2(coord2.y - coord1.y, coord2.x - coord1.x) - Math.Atan2(coord4.y - coord3.y, coord4.x - coord3.x)) * (180 / Math.PI);

        if(result<0)
        {
            result = result + 360;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static List<Point2d> GenerateWaypoints(Point2d Startpoint, Point2d Target)
    {
        List<Point2d> waypoints = new List<Point2d>();
        double tempDistance = 0.0;
        double tempAngle = 30.0 * ( Math.PI/180);

        bool ok = false;
        double distancemodifier = 0.8;
        waypoints.Add(Startpoint);
        tempDistance = Startpoint.distance(ref Target)*distancemodifier;
        Console.WriteLine(tempDistance.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(ReturnStringFromP2D(Startpoint));
        Console.WriteLine(ReturnStringFromP2D(Target));

        Point2d tempPoint2d = CalculateCoordinate(tempAngle, tempDistance);
        Console.WriteLine(ReturnStringFromP2D(tempPoint2d));
        while (!ok)
        {
            tempPoint2d = CalculateCoordinate(tempAngle, tempDistance);
            if (GetAngle(Startpoint, tempPoint2d, tempPoint2d, Target) > 30.00 || tempPoint2d.distance(ref Target) < 10000)
            {
                distancemodifier = distancemodifier - 0.05;
                tempDistance = Startpoint.distance(ref Target) * distancemodifier;
            }
        }
        ok = false;
        waypoints.Add(tempPoint2d);
        waypoints.Add(Target);

        tempAngle = tempAngle + 30.0;
        tempDistance = Target.distance(ref Startpoint) * distancemodifier;
        tempPoint2d = CalculateCoordinate(tempAngle, tempDistance);
        while (!ok)
        {
            tempPoint2d = CalculateCoordinate(tempAngle, tempDistance);
            if (GetAngle(Target, tempPoint2d, tempPoint2d, Startpoint) > 30.00)
            {
                distancemodifier = distancemodifier - 0.05;
                tempDistance = Target.distance(ref Startpoint) * distancemodifier;
            }
        }
        waypoints.Add(tempPoint2d);

        return waypoints;
    }
```

The issue is that I'm not getting anything out of it that makes sense.  The rules I want to apply are that no turn in the flightpath should be larger than 30 degrees. I have the start position, the target position. I want to make sure that the first turn is further than 10km from the target position.

EDIT: OK, here's what I am actually trying to achieve.

Using a 1km grid.
Taking Start point to be 0, 10 and target point to be 10,40, I want to generate a set of waypoints that go from start, to an intermediate step between start and target which should generate a no more than 30 degree angle (but not be a straight line) between the two legs and no closer to target than 5km. Then to target, then back to the start point, with the rule that no angle should be greater than 30 degrees.  Therefore we might get the following (worked out roughly on paper so there might be an error but it should be indicative of what I'm trying to achieve.)
Start 0,10
Intermediate 22,20
Target 10,40
Intermediate -10,48
Intermediate -25,40
Intermediate -35,28
Intermediate -35,14
Intermediate -20,5
Start 0,10

It seems to me that I need three methods, one to return the bearing between two points (used at the start to get the initial direction from start to target  - and then modify away from a straight line), the second to calculate the angle between two lines (used on every step to check the previous angle doesn't exceed 30 degrees), and the third to generate a coordinate given a bearing and a distance from the current location.

From what I understand, my GetAngle() above is correct, and cut down to this will work for bearings between two points??

```
    public static double GetBearing(Point2d coord1, Point2d coord2)         {
        double result = 0.0;

        result = Math.Atan2(coord2.y - coord1.y, coord2.x - coord1.x) * (180 / Math.PI);           
        if(result<0)
        {
            result = result + 360;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Well you're never setting `ok` to true so you'll loop forever. But beside that, what's the input, what output are you getting and what do you expect?

Comment: As part of your research, investigate use of the A* algorithm, a commonly used, efficient path-finding algorithm. You can include logic to prohibit turns larger than 30 degrees, either by just costing such segments so high they aren't used, or by eliminating them outright from consideration.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault I've been messing around with this code so much, commenting in, out, adding/removing the setting of `code`ok has disappeared. Thanks for pointing it out! As for output, input. If I comment out the second portion (ie the return leg) and look at the console outputs, I'm getting a meaningless waypoint, often with negative coordinates.

Comment: @PeterDuniho will look at the A* algorithm. Thanks. I hadn't expected to be able to look at existing path-finding as I don't want the efficient route!.

Comment: Okay, that's a vague representation of the output. Would be better if you edited your question to include the actual output you are currently getting. Also, the exact input you are using and the precise expected/desired output would be nice. Would help in demonstrating the rules you want and debug/test that huge method.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Ah, right. Sorry. I'm a bit new at this. I've probably started the wrong way round, in that the input is variable and being read from a database. Therefore each time I've tested it I've had completely different results. I will get an example test case sorted. Sorry.

Comment: "I don't want the efficient route" -- while A* is usually used to find an efficient route, that's not what I meant. I simply mean the algorithm itself is efficient. You can adjust segment costs and add your own heuristics to ensure that your actual routes are not efficient. :)

Comment: Yeah, if the input always change you'll have a hard time debugging it. IMO you should try to do your algorithm on paper with a fixed input, put some breakpoints in the code and check where the values differs compared to the expected version.

Comment: I've realised on rethinking through my problem that I've gone about this the wrong way I think. Will edit the original post to better explain what I'm trying to do.